# DDR3 memory for HP

Tags: memory, ddr, workstation

I have a HP Z600 Workstation and looking at the memory options on the HP website (https://support.hp.com/gb-en/product/hp-z600-workstation/3718663/model/3718664/document/c01709707) I'm wondering what the difference is between their "CTO" and "AMO" memory?

Comment: CTO in HP parlance means *Configured To Order*. I've not encountered AMO.

Answer (score 0):

AMO seems to be Aftermarket Order, as far as I can find out!
Where CTO is Configure to order!
= CTO is what could be standard delivered from HP and AMO is something you could replace your self (according to what info I could google, with the same problem)
Jesper